# Resize image on the fly Caffe

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, image-resizing

I have a layer called data that takes input image 318x318. When it passes through my convolutional layers, the final size will be 300x300. I would like to combine the 300x300 version of input image to this 300x300 output image from convolutional layers using Elementwise layer in Caffe. Is there any way, I can create this 300x300 image version from 318x318 input image on the fly in caffe?

Or can anybody suggest me the right way of doing this in Caffe ? my approach may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your spatial dimensions are reduced because you are not padding your convolution layers. If you want to precisely fit the input size and the output size, padding the convolutions is probably a better strategy than "resizing on the fly"...

Comment: Shai. Yes you are true, but I read one of the article from Andrej krepathy saying not to do padding. May be I can write one python layer. I will post it after I finish it.

Comment: @Dharma from my experience using.pyyhon layer to resize on the fly kills your net performance. Indeed padding is not recommended, but in your specific scenario, I think it's the lesser evil

Comment: Thank you Shai. Then I will not try the python layer.  May be I will change my approach.